# XP freezes every second

Tags: windows-xp, performance, cpu, freeze

I'm experiencing a problem where XP freezes completely for a fraction of a second, every second. The mouse doesn't update, music stops, video stops - and then suddenly resumes.

I can't see anything using any CPU in Task Manager, and I've tried shutting down every service I can identify. There's nothing obvious in the Event Viewer.

The CPU graph (at highest refresh rate) looks like this for one of the two CPUs:

[image]

The "CPU Usage" alternates between showing 2% and 25% (ie, one CPU 50% utilised).

There is no significant network traffic. I can't think of anything else that could be causing it. Ideas?

UPDATE The next day, it wasn't doing this. But by the end of the day (after several hours sitting idle) it had reappeared. So apparently related to the machine being on for a while.

Comment: How about RAM usage? In Task Manager, look under the Performance tab at 'Physical Memory'. How much as available?

Comment: What does the task manager say is using the CPU?

Comment: Have you scanned for viruses and malware/spyware? Does it do the same thing in all user profiles or Safe Mode?

Comment: Are you running Skype?

Comment: Try checking for updates (Windows and any extra software), maybe it's a bug that has been fixed meanwhile.

Comment: @TheTurkey: Total 3Gb, available 1.3Gb.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Nothing that I can see. System Idle Process at 95%, some other process (eg, Chrome, Explorer, taskmgr, flux...) at 5%, but it changes every refresh. No useful information from task manager I think.

Comment: @DaveM No Skype.

Answer (score 0):

Lately I'd the same problem with my PC, and it turned out that CPU fan is not working.
If the temperature of CPU gets higher, it can make CPU work slower.

Use tools such as AIDA64 to know temperature of your processor.
Or open the case of your PC and look if your fan is working normally.

Comment: Great idea. I use SpeedFan - yes, most sensors are running hot. However, I've now tried putting a huge fan next to the PC (cooling it back to normal range) - still doing it.